# How to make such an option map not JSX?

Tags: reactjs

To run through the array not in the context of jsx, but in the context of the function?

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const array = [
    {
      title: "Hello",
      desc: "World"
    },
    {
      title: "Hello",
      desc: "World"
    },
    {
      title: "Hello",
      desc: "World"
    },
    {
      title: "Hello",
      desc: "World"
    }
  ];

  const onHandleOption = () => {
    return array.map(items => {
      return items.title;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select defaultValue="0">
        <option>{onHandleOption}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to do like this, but it doesn’t work out ...
But if you apply this in the jsx context, then everything works, but I would like to make my code cleaner

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "JSX context"? Also, `onFoobar` should be reserved for event listeners, but this is just a wrapper on `map`. I'd inline it.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work out"? Are you getting an error or just an unexpected results? Because if it's the latter it's probably because you're not adding an option HTML element for every element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mapping them all into the same `option` tag.

If you want to keep in as a separate function try this:

```js
const renderOptions = () => {
  return array.map(item => {
    // Your items don't seem unique so the key here may not work.
    return <option key={item.title}>{item.title}</option>;
  });
};

...

<select defaultValue="0">
  {renderOptions()}
</select>
```